# Google Chrome Cookie php problem

Tags: php, google-chrome, cookies

I'm having problem with cookies on Google Chrome browser. In other browsers site is working correctly. The problem is that when you sign in and than close browser. When you return you're not logged in at first. If you click on any link, then you'll get logged in. So on first visit cookies don't work. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can access a cookie you have to refresh the page. Is is because cookies work like this:

1. your computer sends the request for a page
2. the server sends the page (including headers, and along these headers there can be one telling your computer to store a cookie)
3. when you make another request the computer sends along any previously set cookies

After you set a cookie you *have* to refresh the page in order to use it.

You say you're using Chrome. If you're running OS X there may be another issue: I just discovered Chrome on OS X does not correctly compensate for time zone differences.

If you are GMT + 4 and you set the cookie to expire in less than 4 hours it will expire right away. If you set it to expire in 4 hours and 10 seconds, it will expire in 10 seconds. It's messed up!

Answer (score 0):

First try erasing all cookies, history etc. Then I suggest you check your size limit, then check your directories(move all the files in 1 place). Chrome supports HTML5 localStorage, try it for larger data . Finally check http/https status

Comment: Its not size, because i'm storing int(8), so size is not a problem. Cookies are working fine, just not on first load. On first load it looks like I don't have any cookies at all (for this site).